# How to tint action bar color to white

Tags: android

Adding white icons on action bar from Android image assets they turning to look cream white/grey.

This is the color xml:

```
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
    <color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>
</resources>
```

and this is how my menu item xml:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings"
    android:title="Settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:visible="true"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
    android:title="Settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:visible="true"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_about"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="Test"
    android:visible="true"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
```

and my style xml:

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

[image: This is how it looks]

Comment: Do your icons have an alpha channel?

Answer (score 0):

Action bar has restrict rules for resources, you cannot tweak much with their appearance. If you want full control over Action bar, I would suggest remove the default action bar and implement one yourself using linearlayout or relativelayout or whatever you want.

```
<Your Activity Layout>
    <LinearLayout>
        //Your resources goes here
    </LinearLayout>
    <RelativeLayout>
        //Your Activity resources goes here 
    </RelativeLayout>
</Your Activity Layout>
```

You will have full control over their appearance and functionalities.
Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Please create vector icon from the android studio. 
Right click on the drawable folder in your project.

> drawable > right click > new > vector asset > select icon > change
>   color according to your requirement from xml.

then use this vector asset as a icon.

Hope this will solve your problem